# is it possible to pool together several ubuntu servers in a sort of cloud system?

Tags: server, virtualization

Maybe it is a stupid question.
But I have been thinking I've got several old computers, just lying around.
would it be possible to pool together those computers in to a single "hardware pool" from which ubuntu server could pull it's resources from ? like say I wanted to setup several things like a few VM's and not care about which VM is running on what hardware, just setup a VM and the Servers themselves just figure out where to run that particular VM. is it possible with Ubuntu Server ?

I guess what I'm asking is One server OS, Several Computers as resources to be used ?

Comment: Something like OpenStack can be used I guess. However, that is barely related to Ubuntu. Better ask at [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com)

Comment: The scope of this question goes beyond Ubuntu as an OS. As pLumo mentions, [OpenStack](https://www.openstack.org/) is one option. VM Clustering is another option (can be done with [ProxMox](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Cluster_Manager)). There is also Kubernetes and Docker Swarm. But these are all solutions that go beyond Ubuntu itself.

Comment: so What I'm hearing is; there is no tightly connected Ubuntu server cluster.

Comment: I started looking into this one day and you might be interested in an ubuntu beowulf cluster. I've never done this but again, it might be something worth looking into.

Comment: While I agree to Openstack being the default thought here, there is also https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/docs/master/clustering/ which nowadays can also do KVM based VMs and works better in a cli mode. In general less flexibility, but for that it usually "just works".

Comment: Thanks I will be looking in to this. :)